# Отследить изменения в App.config C#

Tags: c#, файлы

Мне необходимо отследить, что файл App.config изменяется. То есть, если я вношу изменения в него, то должна срабатывать моя функция. Пользуюсь для этого FileSystemWatcher. То, что файл изменился я фиксирую, но когда читаю из него данные, то читаются старые данные. Проблема в работе FileSystemWatcher? Или какой нюанс я упустил? Ниже код, который читает файл. Если нужны ещё какие-то фрагменты, то сообщите, пожалуйста

```
var sites = new List<Site>();
        var section = (ConfigHandler)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("setting");
        foreach (SiteConfigElement l in section.SettingItems)
        {
            sites.Add(new Site(l.Url, l.Email, l.Interval, l.WaitTime));
        }
```

Site это мой класс. В нём хранятся данные.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15819676/5796587

Comment: Проблема в том, что файл меняется не программно, а руками. То есть программа работает, а я открываю файл config и вношу изменения, сохраняю и закрываю

Comment: ну так и добавьте рефреш перед чтением, когда уже отследили факт изменения. Ну чуть-чуть фантазии проявить...

Comment: Вау)) заработало) спасибо огромное

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конфигурация кэшируется, для повышения производительности и вы читаете старые значения из кэша. Когда определили, что app.config был изменен вручную, обновите кэш нужной секции конфигурации перед чтением ([RefreshSection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.refreshsection?view=netframework-4.8))

```
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("setting");
```

Подсмотрено [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15819676/5796587)